# Adoptium JDK installation fails on WSL Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, adoptopenjdk

My intent is to install [OpenJDK 8](https://adoptium.net/installation/linux/), using the docs provided by Microsoft, for the Synapse Spark [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/itemdetails?itemName=SynapseVSCode.synapse).

The Adoptium installation procedure fails in my fresh WSL Ubuntu distro.

```
apt install -y wget apt-transport-https
wget -qO - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/adoptium.gpg > /dev/null
echo "deb https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^jammy/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list
```

results in the following content of the target file:

```
deb https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb  main
```

so trying `sudo apt update` yields

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

So the `echo` command fails in inserting the string argument into the repo URL. When trying to reach the `/artifactory` repo in the browser for debugging, I get redirected to the UI web site. Is there any simple fix for this issue?